# Set access restriction for baseroute

Tags: routes

Let's say I have the following in `example.links.task.yml` from a contributed module:

```
    example.view:
    title: 'View'
    base_route: 'entity.example.canonical'
    route_name: 'entity.example.canonical'

    example.edit_form:
    title: 'Edit'
    base_route: 'entity.example.canonical'
    route_name: 'entity.example.edit_form'

    ... more routes with the same base_route
```

Now I'd like to add a custom access restriction for all these local tasks. I tried to set a restriction to the `base_route`, thinking that all other routes with this particular `base_route` would have the restriction too, but it only works for `entity.example.canonical`. I tried the following way:

```
class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    if (($route = $collection->get('entity.example.canonical'))) {
      $route->setRequirement('_role', 'administrator');
    }
  }

}
```

I could explicitly name all different routes, but I thought there might be a way to only use the `base_route` - not knowing if this would work though. Any ideas?

Comment: Curious, for testing purposes, if you hard code your role requirement in the base route in yml file, same result?

Comment: Thanks, good point! I tried hardcoding it - no difference. And `RouteCollection:all` returns many more routes, not only the ones using the `base_route`. I need to check this though, not sure what `::all` returns in detail.

Comment: Output of `::getIterator` is similar to `::all`

Comment: updated answer, hopefully that will do

Answer (score 1):

This might work

```
if (($route = $collection->get('entity.example.canonical'))) { // base_route
      $current_route = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteObject(); // get current route
      $current_route->setRequirement('_role', 'administrator');
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, but it did not make a difference, only the base_route itself was affected.